# Why Zen-Coding plugin doesn't shows up in SublimeText 2 Package Control?

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm using windows 7, here is a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's Emmet Now](https://github.com/sergeche/zen-coding/blob/master/README.md)

[Link to new site](http://emmet.io/)

[image]